# Как создать TableModel для создания таблицы, состоящей из 2 столбцов?

Tags: c++

В первом столбце String значение, а во втором Int. Может есть где пример или кто может накидать простой пример. Очень нужно. В таблице именно 2 разных типа данных, с одним всё понятно.данных. Просто везде примеры для одного типа данных

Comment: [Пример][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971334

Comment: @oleg77799 не удаляйте свои вопросы! форум не только для вас сделан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [> ***отличный пример*** <](http://javaswing.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/jtabletablemodel/) с использованием TableModel. На данном сайте есть полный листинг кода с объяснением на доступном языке. Только одно но, поля: ***name***, ***size***, ***description*** одного типа, то бишь ***String***. Если вам нужен будет другой, тогда измените на нужный. Ну, думаю, это и так понятно и вы дальше сами разберетесь.